# Fetching and saving to database - Time vs Memory

Tags: database, mongodb, algorithm, julia

Suppose I have a long list of URLs. Now, I need to write a script to do the following -

- Go to each of the URLs
- Get the data returned
- And store it in a database

I know two ways of doing this -

1. Pop one URL from the list, download the data and save it in the database. Pop the next URL, download data and save it in the db, and repeat...

This will require way too many disk writes so, other way is to

2. Download the data from each of the URLs and save it to the memory. And finally, save it all to the database in one disk write.

But this will require carrying a huge chunk of data in the memory. So there's a possibility that program may just terminate because of OOM Error.

Is there any other way, which is some kind of intermediate between these methods?

(In particular, I am writing this script in [Julia](http://julialang.org/) and using [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/))

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: Have you timed the speed? If the bottleneck is in the network (which is usually the case especially if you have SSD), there is probably no much need to bother batching etc. Just remember to keep the program async.

Answer (score 1):

We can extend @Trifon's solution a little bit with concurrency. You could simultaneously run two threads:

1. A thread which fetches the data from the URLs, and stores them in a [channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_(programming)) in the memory.
2. A thread which reads from the channel and writes the data to the disk.

Make sure that the channel has some bounded capacity, so that Thread 1 is blocked in case there are too many consecutive channel writes without Thread 2 consuming them.

Julia is supposed to have good support for [parallel computing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing/)

Answer (score 0):

Write results to the database in batches, say every 1000 URLs.

This solution is something between 1 & 2 of the two ways you are describing above.

Comment: Umm, what makes 1000 a good choice for division? 

What parameters should govern the batch size?